# .net core scaffold-dbcontext - 2 dbcontexts can't add duplicate table names

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I have a .net core 3.1 application with 2 dbcontexts.  Each points to their own, separate, databases.
However, both databases have a couple of tables with the same name:

- Database1 tables (Job and General)
- Database2 tables (Job and General)

I have already added these tables for dbContext1:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=ipaddress;Database=Database1;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Data -Tables "Job","General" -Context dbContext1
```

Now when I try to add these tables for dbContext2 it overwrites the entities created for dbContext1:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=ipaddress;Database=Database2;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Data -Tables "Job","General" -Context dbContext2
```

How can i add the tables for dbContext2 without overwritting the entities created for dbContext1?
Is it possible to alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using different namespaces:
Saved entities for Database1 into Data_DB1 directory and entities for Database2 into Data_DB2 directory